# How to exchange data between renderscript and android framework?

Tags: android, renderscript

I  am new to renderscript. I am trying to add two array elements using renderscript.

I am able to pass the value to renderscript from Android by `invoke_add` method
for coming back to Android framework from renderscript I was suggested to use 
`rsSendToclient()`.

How can I use `rsSendToClient` or any other way for coming back to android framework.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `rsSendToClient(1,  &data, sizeof(data));` in your script and decode the data in Java like this:

```
RSMessageHandler l_resHandler = new RSMessageHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        switch (mID)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                // Handle mData 

            }
            break;
            default: super.run();
                break;
        }
    }

 };
 mRS.setMessageHandler(l_resHandler);
```

But I could not decode the value yet as I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827307/decoding-data-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the code, Fabien. As far as decoding the value is concerned, you can very well use mData within Case 1. mData will hold the data set through rsSendToClient call.